# Can I build a Checker using prebuilt llvm/clang?

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang, clang-static-analyzer

I came across this "How to Write a Checker in 24 Hours - LLVM" by Anna Zaks and Jordan Rose.

I am using an Ubuntu/Debian system.

To build a custom checker, do I need to build llvm and clang from source? 
Anybody knows how use the prebuilt clang and llvm from apt-get to build a checker?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build clang/llvm from the source in order to be able to build a custom checker.

http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/installation.html

When you write a new custom checker, you end up editing the checker related files to register your checker with clang, and recompile it. Which won't be possible with prebuilt executables. How to add your new checker: http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/checker_dev_manual.html